# What does an operative operate?

Tags: nouns, vocabulary

I’m trying to come up with a word which describes the thing an operative operates upon. That is, the target of the operation.

For example, if a surgeon operates on a patient, and a chauffeur operates a car, what generic term describes both the patient and the car?

The best I’ve come up with so far is “operand”, but that has a very specific meaning in mathematics, and doesn’t seem to be used outside of that context.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The most generic term would be operand. Beyond that, you get into field-specific terms. In linguistics, it’s either the *subject* or the *patient* (not the same as a medical patient, but similar word used for similar reasons).

Comment: He pulls strings.

Comment: @DanBron Operand seems to be specific to mathematics, from what I’ve read. Could you point me to some examples of more general usage, please?

Comment: I don't think there is a single, generic word. At best, you can only say something like ***those operated on*** *had to pay their bills*. Or ***those operated*** *had plenty of fuel*. In theory, it could be shortened to just *the operated* (akin to *the poor*), but that sounds awkward because *operated* is not an adjective, and that kind of phrasing isn't normally used. Also note the problem with the presence (or lack) of the preposition. You don't just operate a patient—you operate *on* a patient. On the other hand, you don't operate *on* a car—unless it's in a mechanical sense.

Comment: @JasonBassford All valid points. Thanks Jason.

Comment: Neither a surgeon nor a chauffeur is an "operative."